# Defining methods for types declared in the rule file

Tags: java, drools, kie

Drools has [functionality for declaring new data types](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e6368) in the rule file itself, instead of doing it in the java file.

But how can we define methods for that data type?

For example, if I declare the following type in the rule file:

```
declare Address
   number : int
   streetName : String
   city : String
end
```

How can I add a method to it:

```
public int doubleNumber()
{
  number = number * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getters and setters are provided. You cannot add any methods.

You can write a function with the declared type as an argument.

If this is not sufficient, declare Java types.

Comment: Thanks! Do you, by any chance, know the solution to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40803008/1925388) ?