# how to update rules dynamically in drools rule engine

Tags: drools, rule-engine, kie

i am working on drools rule engine got this scenario to change the values in when block from 1000 to 2000 ,changing the signs from > to <, can we achieve this using a form to edit  the value

```
rule "payment"

when 
   account:Paymentinfo(transaction < 1000)
then
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drools - Ability to define rules at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422106/drools-ability-to-define-rules-at-runtime)

Comment: but i didn't get what i needed from that post can u give any inputs on how to access that drl file into a gui

Comment: @Prog_G I believe the 7-year old question you point to no longer works with the latest version of Drools.

Comment: @bfrguci another alternative to dynamically load rules which works with the latest version of drools is explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530777/7726319